# NSMutableArray saving and loading to Defaults not working properly

Tags: ios, arrays, nsuserdefaults

**SOLVED** it was my bad, i had another if which blocked the method calling. Sorry.

> i have problem saving and loading an NSMutableArray to the
>   NSUSerDefaults. Im going to copy the whole code here, its 2 function.
>   i Think there is some problems with the savving.
>
> ```
>     +(NSArray*)getarenawordsarraywithcheck{
>
>     NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
>     NSArray *array=[defaults arrayForKey:@"arenaszavakosszes"];
>     if ([array count]==0) {
>
>
>             NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arenawordsenglish" ofType:@"plist"];
>             array=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
>             [defaults setObject:array forKey:@"arenaszavakosszes"];
>             [defaults synchronize];
>
>
>     }
>     NSLog(@"Actual Size of the array:%i",[array count]);
>     return array;
> }
> +(void) deletestringfromarenawordsandsaveforstring:(NSString*)actualword{
>
>     NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
>     NSMutableArray *array=[[defaults objectForKey:@"arenaszavakosszes"]mutableCopy] ;
>     NSLog(@"Removing the words: %@ from the words actuall size of the array:%i",actualword,[array count]);
>
>     [array removeObject:actualword];
>     [defaults setObject:array forKey:@"arenaszavakosszes"];
>     [defaults synchronize];
>     NSLog(@"Removed. New size of the array:%i",[array count]);
> }
> ```
>
> UI: I tried to use even the     [defaults
>   mutableArrayValueForKey:@"arenaszavakosszes"]. The problem is, when I
>   try to load the array in the second method it returns nil. Help
>   please.

Comment: post the both nslog value here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `objectForKey` instead of `arrayForKey`:

```
NSArray *array=[defaults objectForKey:@"arenaszavakosszes"];
```